# jqgrid subgrid not working when load once true

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

```js
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "getJsonData",
    async: true,
    mtype: "GET",   
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [                      
        { label: 'TESTID', name: 'testID', width: 60, sorttype: 'integer' ,
          colmenu : true,
          coloptions : {sorting:true, columns: true, filtering: true, seraching:true, grouping:false, freeze : true},
          searchoptions : {
              searchOperMenu : false,
              sopt : ['eq','gt','lt','ge','le']
          }
        },
        { label: 'SUBTESTID', name: 'subTestID', width:80, sorttype: 'string' ,
          colmenu : true,
          coloptions : {sorting:true, columns: true, filtering: true, seraching:true, grouping:false, freeze : true},
          searchoptions : {
              searchOperMenu : false,
              sopt : ['eq','gt','lt','ge','le']
          }
        },
        { label: 'CLIENT', name: 'client', width: 60, sorttype: 'string',
          colmenu : true,
          coloptions : {sorting:true, columns: true, filtering: true, seraching:true, grouping:false, freeze : true},
          searchoptions : {
              searchOperMenu : false,
              sopt : ['eq','gt','lt','ge','le']
          }
        },
        { label: 'RESULTS', name: 'testResults', width: 70, sorttype: 'string',
          colmenu : true,
          coloptions : {sorting:true, columns: true, filtering: true, seraching:true, grouping:true, freeze : true},
          searchoptions : {
              searchOperMenu : false,
              sopt : ['eq','gt','lt','ge','le']
          }
        },
        { lable:"Seq Id", hidden:true, name: 'seqId' }
    ],
    loadComplete: function () {
        var rowIds = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (i = 0; i < rowIds.length; i++) {//iterate over each row
            rowData = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', rowIds[i]);
            if (rowData['testResults'] === "Pass") {
                $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('setRowData', rowIds[i], true, "CSSClass");
            }
            if (rowData['testResults'] == "Fail") {
                $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('setRowData', rowIds[i], true, "CSSClass1");
            }
        }
    }, 
    onSelectRow:function(rowid){
        var rowData = jQuery('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
        if (rowData['testResults'] == "Fail") {
            console.log("clicked");
            $(this).jqGrid("toggleSubGridRow", rowid);
        }
    },
    subGrid: true, 
    subgridtype:"json",
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var rowData = jQuery('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', row_id);
        console.log("rowData:::"+rowData);
        var seqId=rowData['seqId'];

        console.log(seqId)
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
        pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
        $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class=' table2 scroll table-striped table' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;'></table>");
        jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            url:"getCommentsJsonData/"+seqId,
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "GET",
            height:'auto',
            width: 1400,
            colNames: ['File Name','Field Name','Actual Field Value ','Excpected Field Value'],
            colModel: [
                {name:"fileName",index:"fileName"},
                {name:"fieldName",index:"fieldName"},
                {name:"actualFieldValue",index:"actualFieldValue"},
                {name:"excpectedFiledValue",index:"excpectedFiledValue"},
            ],
            loadonce:true,
            rowNum:20
        });
    },
    loadonce: true,
    //navOptions: { reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true } },
    viewrecords: true,
    width: 1390,
    height: 300,
    rowNum: 3000,
    colMenu : true,
    shrinkToFit : true,     
    grouping: true,
    hoverrows:false,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: ["client"],
        groupColumnShow: [true],
        groupText: ["<b>{0}</b>"],
        groupOrder: ["asc"],
        groupSummary: [false],
        groupCollapse: false            
    },
    scroll: 1, // set the scroll property to 1 to enable paging with scrollbar - virtual loading of records
    emptyrecords: 'Scroll to bottom to retrieve new page', // the message will be displayed at the bottom
    sortable: true,
    caption: "ART TEST CASES RESULTS",// set caption to any string you wish and it will appear on top of the grid
    pager: "#jqGridPager"
});

$("#jqGrid").jqGrid("hideCol", "subgrid");   

// activate the build in search with multiple option
$('#jqGrid').navGrid("#jqGridPager", {          
        search: true, // show search button on the toolbar
        add: false,
        edit: false,
        del: false,
        refresh: true,
    },
    {}, // edit options
    {}, // add options
    {}, // delete options
    { multipleSearch: true } // search options - define multiple search
);
$('.colmenu').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}) 
// on chang select value change grouping
jQuery("#chngroup").change(function(){
    var vl = $(this).val();
    if(vl) {
        if(vl === "clear") {
            jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('groupingRemove',true);
        } else {
            jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy',vl);
        }
    }
});
```

When I set loadonce = true in my sub grid not working but when I changed this to loadonce = false then subgrid is working but my pagination and searching functionalities are not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.jgrid.styleUI.Bootstrap.base.rowTable = "  table1 table-bordered";
    var previousRowId = 0;
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "getJsonData",
        async: true,
        mtype: "GET",   
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [                      
            { label: 'TESTID', name: 'testID', width: 60, sorttype: 'integer' ,
              colmenu : true,
              coloptions : {sorting:true, columns: true, filtering: true, seraching:true, grouping:false, freeze : true},
              searchoptions : {
                  searchOperMenu : false,
                  sopt : ['eq','gt','lt','ge','le']
              }
            },
            { label: 'SUBTESTID', name: 'subTestID', width:80, sorttype: 'string' ,
              colmenu : true,
              coloptions : {sorting:true, columns: true, filtering: true, seraching:true, grouping:false, freeze : true},
              searchoptions : {
                  searchOperMenu : false,
                  sopt : ['eq','gt','lt','ge','le']
              }
            },
            { label: 'CLIENT', name: 'client', width: 60, sorttype: 'string' ,
              colmenu : true,
              coloptions : {sorting:true, columns: true, filtering: true, seraching:true, grouping:false, freeze : true},
              searchoptions : {
                  searchOperMenu : false,
                  sopt : ['eq','gt','lt','ge','le']
              }
            },
            { label: 'RESULTS', name: 'testResults', width: 70, sorttype: 'string' ,
              colmenu : true,
              coloptions : {sorting:true, columns: true, filtering: true, seraching:true, grouping:true, freeze : true},
              searchoptions : {
                  searchOperMenu : false,
                  sopt : ['eq','gt','lt','ge','le']
              }
            },
            {
              lable:"Seq Id",
              hidden:true, 
              name: 'seqId'              
            }
        ],
        loadComplete: function () {
            var rowIds = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (i = 0; i < rowIds.length; i++) {//iterate over each row
                rowData = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', rowIds[i]);

                if (rowData['testResults'] === "Pass") {    
                    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('setRowData', rowIds[i], true, "CSSClass");
                } 
                if (rowData['testResults'] == "Fail") {
                    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('setRowData', rowIds[i], true, "CSSClass1");
                } 
            } 
        }, 
        onSelectRow:function(rowid){
            var rowData = jQuery('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
            if (rowData['testResults'] == "Fail") {
                console.log("clicked");
                $(this).jqGrid("toggleSubGridRow", rowid);
            }
        },
        subGrid: true, 
        subgridtype:"json",
        subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
            var rowData = jQuery('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', row_id);
            console.log("rowData:::"+rowData);
            var seqId=rowData['seqId'];

            console.log(seqId)
            subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
            pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
            $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class=' table2 scroll table-striped table' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;'></table>");
            jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                url:"getCommentsJsonData/"+seqId,
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "GET",
                height:'auto',
                width: 1400,
                colNames: ['File Name','Field Name','Actual Field Value ','Excpected Field Value'],
                colModel: [
                    {name:"fileName",index:"fileName"},
                    {name:"fieldName",index:"fieldName"},
                    {name:"actualFieldValue",index:"actualFieldValue"},
                    {name:"excpectedFiledValue",index:"excpectedFiledValue"},
                ],
                loadonce:true,
                rowNum:20
            });
        },
        loadonce: true,
        //navOptions: { reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true } },
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 1390,
        height: 300,
        rowNum: 3000,
        colMenu : true,
        shrinkToFit : true,     
        grouping: true,
        hoverrows:false,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ["client"],
            groupColumnShow: [true],
            groupText: ["<b>{0}</b>"],
            groupOrder: ["asc"],
            groupSummary: [false],
            groupCollapse: false            
        },
        scroll: 1, // set the scroll property to 1 to enable paging with scrollbar - virtual loading of records
        emptyrecords: 'Scroll to bottom to retrieve new page', // the message will be displayed at the bottom
        sortable: true,
        caption: "ART TEST CASES RESULTS",// set caption to any string you wish and it will appear on top of the grid
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
    });

    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("hideCol", "subgrid");   

    // activate the build in search with multiple option
    $('#jqGrid').navGrid("#jqGridPager", {          
            search: true, // show search button on the toolbar
            add: false,
            edit: false,
            del: false,
            refresh: true,
        },
        {}, // edit options
        {}, // add options
        {}, // delete options
        { multipleSearch: true } // search options - define multiple search
    );
    $('.colmenu').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }) 
    // on chang select value change grouping
    jQuery("#chngroup").change(function(){
        var vl = $(this).val();
        if(vl) {
            if(vl === "clear") {
                jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('groupingRemove',true);
            } else {
                jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy',vl);
            }
        }
    });     
});
```

Comment: You should post the JavaScript code, which you use. It's clear, that every thing can be used in correct and incorrect way. One have to know more details about the usage. Moreover it's strictly recommended to include **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Many questions about jqGrid uses "free-jqgrid" tag, but using other product.

Comment: thanks @oleg the version i am using is Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.2.1

Comment: You can open the file `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` in text editor and to see comment as the beginning of the file (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v5.2.1/js/grid.base.js#L4-L9) too). It contains [the URL](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) with description of license agreement and **the prices** which you have to pay. In other words you use currently **commercial** product "Guriddo jqGrid JS". I develop alternative product under the name "free jqGrid" available under MIT or GPL licenses **completely free of charge**. In any way, one needs to know JavaScript code to help you.

Comment: You should click on "edit" link below of the text of your question and append the text of your question with any additional information, like the code. [The article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) provides tips about formatting of the code. Most common is selection of the code and clicking on `{}` button, which will include 4 spaces at the beginning of every line of the code.

Comment: @preethikoochana, please post you Guriddo jqGrid code which demostrates your poblem in order to help

Comment: @oleg posted my js code .

Comment: @preethikoochana: You use Guriddo jqGrid JS and I develop *alternative* fork. Thus I'd address your question to Tony Tomov. One thing, which I'd recommend you to do independent on the fork and version of jqGrid: **remove `scroll: 1` option**, which could bring you more problems as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will say wow!!! you try to use fast all the properties of the grid in one grid.

Lets go from the beginning.

1. The grid option

   ...
   async : true,
   ...

is put wrong and it does not have effect. To have effect this option should be  put in ajaxGridOptions object. See [docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options), but to be honest this option in ajax is by default true, so there is no need to use it.

2. The code in grid complete is total ineffective. 
   With the same success and more elegant is to use [rowattr event](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#events) 
   This mean you do not need to use getRowData and setRowData methods and just to analyse the row and put the appropriate class.
3. I'm not sure what you try to use in onSelectRow.
   I suggest you first to disable this event, which causes your problems
   and show the subgrid row which you hide
4. The option scroll : 1 will not work if grouping is enabled grouping : true

What I suggest you first is to fix these problems in the grid and then 
let us know if there is a problem.

Comment: thanks @Tony Tomov I have done the changes you discussed.Removed async : true from code.I have commented the block of code  onSelectRow  and unhide the subgrid row and also commented the scroll:1 option. But still facing the same issue subgrid is working only if loadoce:false.I want sungrid with loadonce:true.

Comment: Hello, I tested your code and found a bug when grouping, subgrid and loadonce are set to true. I have [fixed the problem](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ec1545543683093bfcc220fd50a20a4d85dcbed2). Until to publish the changes  you can reload the grid after all the code something like this `setTimeout( function() { $("#jqGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");},100);`

Comment: @preethikoochana,  glad to help